# Need to display mutliple images at a time in jsp which are came from db

Tags: java

My code is like  below
        first.jsp

```
     <%
            List<BpsBiller> bpsBiller = (List<BpsBiller>)session.getAttribute("biller");
        System.out.println("bpsBiller size ----->"+bpsBiller.size());

             for(BpsBiller biller:bpsBiller){
                byte[] imageData =new byte[1024];  
                imageData = (byte[])biller.getIcon();
                session.removeAttribute("blobData");
                session.setAttribute("blobData",imageData);

            %>
            <span style="padding:10px;">    
            <a href="javascript:fetchBillerFields('<%=biller.getBillerId()%>');">       

                <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/transactions/billerImages.jsp"  alt="biller logo" border="1" height="50" width="50">

            </a> 
            </span> 
        <%      

            }

        %>
```

And my billerImages.jps code is like

```
<%
try{

    byte[] imageData =new byte[1024];
    imageData = (byte[])session.getAttribute("blobData");

    int len = imageData.length;

    if(imageData!=null){

        int len1 = imageData.length;        


        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");      
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" +"test");

        response.getOutputStream().write(imageData,0,len);          
        response.getOutputStream().flush();        
        response.getOutputStream().close();
       System.out.println("5");
    }
    System.out.println("6");
    session.removeAttribute("blobData");


}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("--error--"+e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

In the First.jsp i am getting the billers list as bpsBiller from session. In this I have billerId. Based on billerId i am displaying image.

I am displaying image using billerImages.jsp.
And the images are coming from existing database table. Billers list is the one which I put it in the session. The icons(blob datatype) coming from this session. getAttribute("billers");

I am using hibernate. "billers" is the list of billers which are coming from Struts2 Action Class.. I used hibernate for retrieving the billers from the database

But My problem is that  I am getting the list. and I have no.of images in the db. If 10 records in the list,10 images are showing.. but only 10th image is displaying for all 1-10 records. I should have to get total 10 different images.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the image in the session as a blob. Instead, pass the image id as a parameter:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/transactions/billerImages.jsp?id=<%=biller.getBillerId()%>"  alt="biller logo" border="1" height="50" width="50">
```

And make your `billerImages.jsp` retrieve that parameter and query the database and return the image that belongs to it each time.

If you still want to use the session as a way to store the image, just don't use the same attribute for all the images:

session.setAttribute("blobData" + biller.getId(),imageData);

Comment: In general, even if this means more change to your code, I would use the first approach to avoid clogging the session with data. Also, in `byte[] imageData = new byte[1024];`, you do not need to create the array (the reference is overwritten at the next line)

Comment: am displaying image using billerImages.jsp. And the images are coming from existing database table. Billers list is the one which I put it in the session. The icons(blob datatype) coming from this session. getAttribute("billers");

I am using hibernate. "billers" is the list of billers which are coming from Struts2 Action Class.. I used hibernate for retrieving the billers from the database